# The best way to query json data in oracle table with multiple search parameters and dynamic json data?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I need to search oracle database table which contains json document field.
I have it working relying on **KEEP** operator, here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7NUXXBKH) demonstrating the essence of the problem.
And here is the gist of the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  D.JSONDOC DOC,
  JSON_TRANSFORM(D.JSONDOC, KEEP  '$.* ?(@ like "S104%")') AS JSONDOC
FROM master_data D
```

This sql returns all the fields satisfying `like "S104%"` criteria.

Now I need to use multiple search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it using `KEEP` operator to it's **full extent**:

> KEEP — Remove all parts of the input data that are not targeted by at least one of the specified path expressions. A topmost object or array is not removed; it is emptied, becoming an empty object ({}) or array ([]).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  D.JSONDOC DOC,
  JSON_TRANSFORM(D.JSONDOC, KEEP  '$.* ?(@ like "S104%")', '$.* ?(@ like "%bla%")') AS JSONDOC
FROM master_data D
```